# How use The youtube subscription_manager

Tags: android, youtube, rss, subscription

I have the subscription_manager file that has I think RSS content.
file content Channels info that I am there's subscription.

how I can use that file in android app?

this is part of the file :

```
<opml version="1.1">
<body><outline text="YouTube Subscriptions" title="YouTube Subscriptions"><outline text="Sahar TheTallWitch" title="Sahar TheTallWitch" type="rss" xmlUrl="https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UC7vYWtZShDLheammtHJpOLw" /><outline text="Appscrip" title="Appscrip" type="rss" xmlUrl="https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UC7U65c_o1hNwiwTkWXG32fg" /><outline text="Moha" title="Moha" type="rss" xmlUrl="https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCOGZxFbYklj2N1Lxf1OYOeA" /><outline text="freeCodeCamp.org" title="freeCodeCamp.org" type="rss"
```

[image]

Comment: You need to parse that data.